# Add a column based on the query value for the distinct with INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, distinct

I have these two tables

TABLEA

```
   ID             SQLUID                       GNO  etype   someoID   prevVal        TBUID
    1   637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA    33    1        7       3        F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    
    2   F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    33    1        7       3        F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8
```

TABLEB

```
ID   CID GNO   STANCE someoID  AadharNO   PanID   VoterID timestamp      EndTime    Name  Status       TBGUID
7    5   33     1      7        0          7       7      1640286493    1640286496  Hari   8     48E587DD-9835-438F-95F7-E254803E5702
8    5   33     1      7        0          7       7      1640286694    1640286697  Prasad 0     637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA
10   5   33     1      7        0          1       1      1640325568    1640325588  Verma  4     B1895540-2806-463E-A651-C3785ECBC18D
```

Now I am doing a INNER JOIN on these two tables which gives me

```
SELECT TABLEA.TBUID, 
       TABLEA.someoID, 
       TABLEB.GNO, 
       TABLEA.SQLUID, 
       TABLEB.TBGUID, 
       TABLEA.etype 
FROM TABLEA 
INNER JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.someoID = TABLEB.someoID
```

RESULT

```
    TABLEA.TBUID                 TABLEA.someoID     TABLEB.GNO     TABLEA.SQLUID                    TABLEB.TBGUID                        TABLEA.etype
F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    7            33       637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA  637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA    1
F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    7            33       637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA  B1895540-2806-463E-A651-C3785ECBC18D    1
F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    7            33       637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA  48E587DD-9835-438F-95F7-E254803E5702    1
F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    7            33       F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8  637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA    1
F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    7            33       F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8  B1895540-2806-463E-A651-C3785ECBC18D    1
F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    7            33       F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8  48E587DD-9835-438F-95F7-E254803E5702    1
```

Now what I need is DSITINCT ON TABLEA.TBUID,TABLEA.someoID,TABLEB.GNO,TABLEA.SQLUID, TABLEA.etype and the status value present in TABLEB for `TABLEA.SQLUID`

So my result would be

```
TABLEA.TBUID                     TABLEA.someoID     TABLEB.GNO     TABLEA.SQLUID                    TABLEB.status TABLEA.etype
F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    7               33       637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA   0           1
F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8    7               33       F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8   NULL        1
```

As you can see the status for `F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8` is NULL as this value is not present in `TABLEB.TBGUID`

I tried using this way, but this does not works for me

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLEA.TBUID,
                TABLEA.someoID,
                TABLEB.GNO,
                TABLEA.SQLUID,
                TABLEB.status,
                TABLEA.etype 
FROM TABLEA 
INNER JOIN TABLE ON TABLEA.someoID = TABLEB.someoID
```

Comment: Your first query cannot produce your first result...

Comment: what do you mean? how?

Comment: tableb status is never 637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA

Comment: edited the results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many conditions in the on statement as you need and a left join is more appropriate

```
SELECT TABLEA.TBUID, 
       TABLEA.someoID, 
       TABLEB.GNO, 
       TABLEA.SQLUID, 
       tableb.status,
         TABLEA.etype 
FROM TABLEA 
left JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.someoID = TABLEB.someoID and tbguid = sqluid;

+--------------------------------------+---------+------+--------------------------------------+--------+-------+
| TBUID                                | someoID | GNO  | SQLUID                               | status | etype |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------+--------------------------------------+--------+-------+
| F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8 |       7 |   33 | 637F284D-EA28-406D-84A2-5367972A32FA |      0 |     1 |
| F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8 |       7 | NULL | F3F3875C-4E34-4FA1-83DE-AA087495BDE8 |   NULL |     1 |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------+--------------------------------------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Note gno has to be null for the same reason that status is null

Comment: The problem is I cannot use JOIN on more than one columns, is there no other way? and inner join with distinct needs to be used

Comment: Have you been told to do it that way or is there some other reason what you cannot left join and use more than 1 column?

Comment: It's an old code base of a open source project, can't do much changes with query as everything else would break

Comment: An inner join can only return from both tables on an exact match you could check the result of what is returned against tablea but that starts to be a radical code change and I don't think you want to go there.(I don't)

Comment: And if stuff breaks because of a requirement change than that's just the way it is and you need to impact assess all the way through the code base.

Comment: How about I store the result in a temp table then again add this other column in a separate query

Comment: Is that not a change to the query?

Comment: What I mean is let the previous query be as it as, store the result in a temp table, then do a join on the TABLEB again and add this another column by joining on tbguid = sqluid